# apache pig load data with multiple delimiters

Tags: apache-pig, delimiter

Hi everyone I have a problem about loading data using apache pig, the file format is like:

```
"1","2","xx,yy","a,sd","3"
```

So I want to load it by using the multiple delimiter `","` 2double quotes and one comma like:

```
A = LOAD 'file.csv' USING PigStorage('","') AS (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5);
```

but the PigStorage doesn't accept the multiple delimiter `","`.How I can do it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

PigStorage takes single character as delimiter.You will have use builtin functions from [PiggyBank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank). Download piggybank.jar and save in the same folder as your pigscript.Register the jar in your pigscript.

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar;

DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();

A = LOAD 'test1.txt' USING CSVLoader(',') AS (f1:int,f2:int,f3:chararray,f4:chararray,f5:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,f2,f3,f4,f5;
DUMP B;
```

Alternate option is to load the data into a line and then use [STRSPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#strsplit)

```
A = LOAD 'test1.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, '","'));
DUMP B;
```

Comment: this was one of my problems and it really helped me to solve one part of it. very useful thanks. could you please have a look at this also comments if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942521/rule-of-thumb-for-reading-from-a-file-and-defining-schema-for-complex-data-struc